# Live tile background changing windows 8

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, live-tile

I created a live tile, but I don't know how to change the background color. This is Windows 8 and C#.

Comment: You have many questions with simple things. Why don't you start reading some info and doing some tutorials instead of just asking for solutions?
I think that you we'll be a better coder if you do that before asking

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 8 Live Tile logo like stock in footer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644095/windows-8-live-tile-logo-like-stock-in-footer)

Comment: Have you checked out [the Windows 8 conference presentation on live tiles](http://channel9.msdn.com/events/BUILD/BUILD2011/APP-396T)?

Answer (score 2):

The Background color of the Tile is defined in manifest configuration of your app.

You can change the color of your tile in Package.appxmanifest "Tile>Background Color"